# Django on tornado production environment advice

Tags: django, tornado

I was looking for ways to combine Django and tornado and I came across https://github.com/koblas/django-on-tornado

Is there anyone who have tried this setup? Is there any difference ( in terms of coding and production environment issues ) in using the above setup 
as compared to writing an app in Tornado only?

What are the things do i have to look out for if I am using the above setup?

best.

Answer (score 1):

[Tornado Web Framework in Production With Django and Nginx](http://www.jeremybowers.com/blog/post/3/on-deploying-tornado-web-server-framework/)